# Is there an out-of-the-box way to manage 1:n data in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, point, attribute-table, relates

I think an image explains the question best:

[image]

What I basically want to do is select the object, view its attributes and from there call the second table to view/edit/add status entries. Since I can't just do a 1:n join, the tables are separate right now and the status table requires a manual OBJID entry (via value-relation dropdownbox) every time a new record is added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This use case should be covered by the **Relations** feature: see [User Manual - Creating one to many relations](http://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#creating-one-to-many-relations) or [Matthias Kuhn's QGIS Relations](http://blog.vitu.ch/10112013-1201/qgis-relations) post.

[image]

Comment: Hi, your supplied urls talk about a "Form".  I do not see these.  How do I get a Form to display?  Thanks much!

Comment: @StuSmith Please open a new thread if you have a new question.